# Is "International" a meta tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Does the term [international](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international) mean anything by itself, or is it a "Meta tag", something that can only work when it's combined with another tag?

Additionally, using "International" to mean "Outside the United States" in [Is the abortion debate as divisive outside the US as it is inside?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/726/is-the-abortion-debate-as-divisive-outside-the-us-as-it-is-inside) is a tad US-centric - I suspect "Worldwide" would be a better tag.

Answer (score 1):

I was using international to denote worldwide comparison.  I am not wedded to it however.